# Troubleshooting Dart XMLHttpRequest error - works for Flutter mobile, not for Flutter web

Tags: python, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, xmlhttprequest

I'm fairly new to Dart and am having a hard time troubleshooting this error that appears in a fair number of questions here:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
```

My real-life scenario is a Flutter web app that's supposed to hit a Google Cloud Function, but in the spirit of MWEs I've replicated the issue with this Dart:

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> main() async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.https(
        //'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 'albums'),
        'my-region-my-project.cloudfunctions.net',
        '/remainingTrigger'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      //'Content-Type': 'application/json; '
      //    'charset=UTF-8',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      //'title': 'test',
      'ingredients': 'test',
    }),
  );
  log('response was ${response.body}');
}
```

The `headers` comments don't seem to make a difference either way, but if I flip the other comments, it works fine with JSONPlaceholder. If I hit my Cloud Function with `curl` in a terminal

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"ingredients": "test"}' https://my-region-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/remainingTrigger
{"key":"value","otherKey":"otherValue"}
```

it works fine. I did originally have an issue with CORS (my Cloud Function logs showed 417) but after I added

```
from flask import abort
def entryPoint(request):
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }
        return ('', 204, headers)
...
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
...
        return (expectedOutput, 200)
...
    else:
        return abort(417)
```

the Cloud Function logs started showing normal behavior (first 204, then 200). If the Cloud Function says everything is fine, and Dart doesn't agree, does that rule out CORS as the culprit? I've only dealt with CORS once, but I set the Cloud Function up very similarly and the web developer was able to interact with it fine.

The traceback is Greek to me; does anybody have advice for discerning what type of `XMLHttpRequest` issue is causing the error?

I'm mainly troubleshooting this in Android Studio 4.1.3 (Chrome emulator) running on Windows 10 Home (`http: ^0.13.1`, Dart SDK 2.12.2, Flutter 2.0.4, Android SDK 29.0.2), but also built and deployed it once to my site, which encountered the same error (Safari). I'm deploying the Cloud Function (Python 3.8 runtime) from a Docker container on Big Sur 11.0.1 but I don't see that making a difference.

---

### Update 1

To my surprise, this works fine when I try my code in Android Studio's Android emulator (Pixel 3, API 30, Android 11.0). It's just the Flutter web attempts that fail (I've now tried with both Chrome and Edge through Android Studio, and Safari in production). Does anybody else see this behavior?

### Update 2

I'm also seeing this behavior with a vendor's API, so it's not specific to my Google Cloud Function. Is there something special about the combination of Flutter for web and the JSONPlaceholder API that makes it work?

Comment: Ever find a solution? I am having the same experience and not utilizing cors, with the latest http 0.13.4.

Comment: @Booyah Sadly I have not; I just put the work to the side. I'm hoping to pick it back up at some point this year, but I'm still not sure what direction to head in.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it seemed to be a cross orgin related. It can be fixed by sending {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'} with the response in the cloud function. The response should look like this:

```
return ('Any response body', 200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})
```

Comment: This is it. Cloud function return although successful, it seems you need to provide it the status and ACAO.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a CORS issue still. Firebase recently released [gen 2 Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade) with an easier way to add CORS.

Allow all origins:

```
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

exports.sayHello = onRequest(
  { cors: true },
  (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello world!");
  }
);
```

Allow your origin:

```
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

exports.sayHello = onRequest(
  { cors: ["my-site.com"] },
  (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello world!");
  }
);
```